# Avoid setting mark when using js-beautify, while remembering position

Tags: vim

I have created a mapping in Vim which:

1. creates a mark (mq)
2. calls js-beautify with a few options
3. jumps back to mark ('q)
4. removes the mark (mq)

This is supposed to happen with one keypress, and it works fine; however, the mark **q** reappears after a while (only a few seconds).

```
autocmd FileType javascript noremap <buffer> <c-f> mq:%!js-beautify -s 2 -j -q -f -<CR>'q<esc>mq<esc>zz<esc>
```

I'm guessing there's something wrong about how I execute consecutive commands, but not sure what?

Maybe there's a better solution that I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK `mq` will not remove a mark just overwrite the `q` mark with the current location. You want `:delmarks q` to delete the mark.

Comment: @FDinoff ah, that seems to have solved it. :) Add as an answer, and I'll accept it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mq` does not remove marks it just overwrites the mark with the current position. To delete marks you want to use `:delmarks q`.